# How to delete a child record from xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

I am trying to delete a ChildRecord `<cat>` in xml. Nothing is worked correctly.

**Here is Source XML**

```
  <Main>
    <Student>
      <name>paul</name>
    </Student>
    <cat>
      <category>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Architecture</name>
      </category>
      <category>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Education</name>
      </category>
    </cat>
  </Main>
```

I tried this code. But not worked.

```
  XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
  xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("main.xml"));
  XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("cat");
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
  xdoc.RemoveChild(node);
  }
```

**Error** I'm seeing
{System.ArgumentException: The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Please help me.

Result XML should looks like

```
  <Main>
    <Student>
      <name>paul</name>
    </Student>
  </Main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier with [Linq2Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
xDoc.Root.Element("cat").Remove();
xDoc.Save(filename);
```

PS: namespace: *System.Xml.Linq*

**EDIT**

Using XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("main.xml"));

XmlNode node = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("cat")[0];
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

xdoc.Save(filename);
```